# Ask permission for Facebook user

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, email

I am using the following code to get Data on the logged Facebook user for my codeigniter application.

```
require_once('facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php');

        $facebook= new Facebook(array(
          'appId' => $this->config->item('app_id'),
              'secret' => $this->config->item('app_secret'),
              'allowSignedRequest' => false,
        ));

        $_REQUEST += $_GET;
        $user = $facebook->getUser();

        if ($user) {
          try {

            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=picture.width(100).height(100),first_name,last_name,username,email');

          } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            $user = null;
          }
        } else {
           $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope' => 'email'
            ));
             echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        }
```

This works and returns me the user's Facebook data, and if no user is logged in it provides the login link.

In the login link I ask for email permission as I need to collect these for communication. When the user logs in  with the login link in the else clause, I successfully get the user's email address.

However I want to launch this application in a Facebook page tab using Woobox. Therefore the user would usually always be logged into their account. But the login to get email permissions is in the else statement if the user isn't logged in.

How do I ask for email permissions for an already logged in user, without haveing them login again?

How can I make it so that if the user is already logged into facebook, that the auth box asking the user for permissions comes up, where they can click ok to continue and authorize, rather than the login button.

Comment: Logged into Facebook and logged into your app are not the same thing, you need to use the same login process to get the users' permission

Comment: @lgy  So it is fine to have a user login again inside a Facbook tab. BTW, it's a website url that I would be using inside woobox.